# How can I get different datasets, all in one excel sheet

Tags: r, excel, import

I have 5 databases (`DEMOGRAPHIE, CARACTERISTIQUE, FIN, EI ,EIG`)  all on the same excel sheet. I will have to retrieve each database without having to copy and paste.

This is how the different databases look on the Excel sheet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think there are 3 empty rows between each database (but I don't know if this will always be the case).

And there is a row before each dataset corresponding to the title of the dataset. There is a general pattern that indicates where one dataset ends and another begins, but I have no idea how to retrieve each database while keeping the column names in the header

And that is how the datasets appear after importing.

I am wondering if it is more easy to select each after importing or during importing in R

Comment: You will probably need some predictable pattern that separates the data to do this. E.g. if you are going to look for a run of 3 empty values in the first column you need to know you'll never encounter missing values inside a table and that it always starts with the name. Also, it seems the width is variable so you'll need some set of rules for finding the edge of the data. But if you have suitably robust heuristics for those things, this can be done with `readxl::read_excel()`.

Comment: Or if it's always exactly those 5 tables, do you know the exact location in the sheet? If so that's pretty easy. You can feed those coordinates directly into `readxl::read_excel()`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the number of columns varies depending on the dataset. This is for this particular study, but I want to write a more general program, since the number of tables will vary from one study to another. And the rule of 3 empty rows between the different tables I don't know if it is always the case. But I think that the application that generates the database separates each form by 3 rows

Comment: I think there is a pattern to the empty spaces between the different datasets. These 3 empty rows are empty (especially the first column). As far as datasets are concerned they may have empty cells, but never for the first column

Comment: Ok, that's helpful, I'll see what I can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are always 3 blank rows separating the tables and they always start with the table name and then column names, the following should work.

Here we first read in the raw data and then parse it to find the positions of each table (using the 3 blank row rule). This is done by finding a `match` for a string of 3 `NA` values which is how `read_excel()` reads blank rows.

For the width, this solution takes advantage of the fact that if you specify the start and end rows, `read_excel()` can guess the width. Therefore you don't have to figure that out as long as there's nothing else in the table that would confuse it.

For the purposes of demonstration, I made up a minimal sample file with just the first 3 lines of `mtcars` and `iris` but it should scale to any arbitrary size.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl) # for creating test input

# sample data
d <- structure(list(...1 = c("MTCARS", "mpg", "21", "21", "22.8", NA, NA, NA, "IRIS", "Sepal.Length", "5.0999999999999996", "4.9000000000000004", "4.7"), ...2 = c(NA, "cyl", "6", "6", "4", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Sepal.Width", "3.5", "3", "3.2"), ...3 = c(NA, "disp", "160", "160", "108", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Petal.Length", "1.4", "1.4", "1.3"), ...4 = c(NA, "hp", "110", "110", "93", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Petal.Width", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2"), ...5 = c(NA, "drat", "3.9", "3.9", "3.85", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Species", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa"), ...6 = c(NA, "wt", "2.62", "2.875", "2.3199999999999998", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...7 = c(NA, "qsec", "16.46", "17.02", "18.61", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...8 = c(NA, "vs", "0", "0", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...9 = c(NA, "am", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...10 = c(NA, "gear", "4", "4", "4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...11 = c(NA, "carb", "4", "4", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
d %>% write_xlsx("test.xlsx", format_headers = F, col_names = F)

# read in raw data
raw_input <- read_excel("test.xlsx", col_names = F)

# take first column to find each table
first_col <- raw_input %>% pull(1)

# find positions for each table
table_start_rows <- c(1, which(first_col %in% c(NA,NA,NA))[c(T,F,F)] + 3) + 1
table_end_rows <- c(which(first_col %in% c(NA,NA,NA))[c(T,F,F)] - 1, length(first_col))
table_lengths <- table_end_rows - table_start_rows
# extract table names
table_names <- first_col[table_start_rows - 1]

# read in each table and capture into list
l <- map2(.x = (table_start_rows - 1),
     .y = table_lengths,
     .f = ~read_excel("test.xlsx", skip = .x, n_max = .y))

# add table names
names(l) <- table_names

# inspect output
l
#> $MTCARS
#> # A tibble: 3 × 11
#>   mpg   cyl   disp  hp    drat  wt                 qsec  vs    am    gear  carb 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.62               16.46 0     1     4     4    
#> 2 21    6     160   110   3.9   2.875              17.02 0     1     4     4    
#> 3 22.8  4     108   93    3.85  2.3199999999999998 18.61 1     1     4     1    
#> 
#> $IRIS
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   Sepal.Length       Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>   <chr>              <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>  
#> 1 5.0999999999999996 3.5         1.4          0.2         setosa 
#> 2 4.9000000000000004 3           1.4          0.2         setosa 
#> 3 4.7                3.2         1.3          0.2         setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for these scripts which are very useful. They work overall, but the function `match ` only takes into account the first three blank rows and not the subsequent blanks. This ends up giving me only the first two datasets. I try to modify the part of the scripts with the function `match `

Comment: I think that codes allow me to retrieve the first two datasets, not more, but it give me some idea of how achieve the goal

Comment: I end up to solve the problem by scripts less sophisticated. But it works,  `temp<-which(first_col%in%NA)` ;
`temp2<-length(temp)`;
`temp3<-seq(1,temp2, by=3)`;
`temp4<-temp[temp3]`; I spot the index of first NA after each table

Comment: You're right, I forgot that `match` only returns the first match. See updated code that should work - very similar to your comment.

Comment: Thank your codes are more succint